# How to get part of a script using Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get coordinates from HTML source, I obtain a string with the script that keeps the coordinates using:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.pl/maps?source=tldsi&hl=pl").get();
Element scriptElement = doc.getElementsByTag("script").first();
```

And the output is following:

```
<script>
  mapslite = {
    START_TIME: new Date()
  };
  mapslite.getBasePageResponse = function(cacheResponse) {
    delete mapslite.getBasePageResponse;
    cacheResponse([[[19763.02300843847,19.416411,51.7444121],[0,0,0],[1024,768],13.10000038146973],"/maps-lite/js/2/maps_lite_20151130_RC02/intl/pl_ALL",null,null,null,["pl-PL","pl"],["/maps/lite/ApplicationService.GetEntityDetails","/maps/lite/ApplicationService.UpdateStarring","/maps/lite/ApplicationService.Search",null,"/maps/lite/suggest","/maps/lite/directions","/maps/lite/MapsLiteService.GetHotelAvailability"],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"/maps/api/js?client=google-maps-lite\u0026libraries=common,geometry,map,search\u0026v=3.23.1\u0026language=pl-PL\u0026region=pl\u0026callback=v3loaded\u0026inline_main_and_libraries=1","/maps-lite/js/2/maps_lite_20151130_RC02/intl/pl_ALL/main.js",0,"Java/1.8.0_45,gzip(gfe)",null,null,0,0,null,"https://www.google.pl/maps/@?source=tldsi\u0026hl=pl\u0026dg=dbrw\u0026newdg=1",0,null,0,null,null,"HL9lVvOvF5WpNKH-s9gM",null,null,["dbrw",1],null,null,null,null,0,null,null,null,[0,0,null,0,1,null,null,null,0,0,1,1,0,"map,common",1,0,0,0,0],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"//consent.google.com","2.maps_lite_20151130_RC02"]);
  };
</script>
```

19.416411,51.7444121 in cacheResponse are the coordinates that I need to get, please help me.

Comment: What is stopping you from reading that string line by line, checking if line starts with `cacheResponse([[[` and substring parts you are interested in (`indexOf` method can be helpful to determine positions of `,` and `]` which should be used with substring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup does not interpret or parse the contents of script tags. The only thing that you can do is to get the content of the script as string and then use a better fitting parser for that. Regular expressions could do the job. Maybe you need to parse some strings with a JSON parser. For your problem I would:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cacheResponse\\(\\[+([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+),([0-9.]+)");
```

The groups 2 and 3 contain the coordinates that you wanted: 19.416411 and 51.7444121

Comment: There was a small error in the pattern. I fixed it. If that answer solves your problems, please consider accepting the answer.